# How to change the video source after clicking the button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'd like to perform the function that to change the video source after clicking the button. However, I've used many methods but after clicking, the videoplayer still didn't change the source.
Here is my code: (I've ommitted some unnecessary code)
HTML:

```
<video id="my-player">
    <source id='source' src='' type="application/dash+xml"></source>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
</video>
<button id='dashsample' onclick='dashSample(); return false'>Dash Sample</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function dashSample(){
    var video = document.getElementById('my-player');
    var source = document.getElementById('source');
    var newsource = 'http://dai-ce14453a15d70c42.elb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/awt/media/dash/cosmo/cosmo1/manifest.mpd';
    source.setAttribute('src',newsource);  
    video.load();
    //play when ready
    video.play();    
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your current code seems to be working fine and switched the `src` just as you wanted when I tested it locally. Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Yes, the error is VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this media. I've used the google chrome server, does this also matter for the version of server?

Comment: I don't think the HTML5 video tag currently supports `.mpd` format. Try switching the source linkto an `.mp4` video and you'll notice that the JavaScript switches the video source as it should. The problem is with the `.mpd` format of your file.

Comment: I‘ve used the video-js library so it actually can support .mpd form. Here is my added code in the header: ```<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.11.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"> <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.11.4/video.min.js"></script>```